# How do I prevent the to execute the code of if statement instead of elif statement code

Tags: python, if-statement, cgi

When the user sign up it shows the if print statement with no value not the elif print statement.
i tried to make a database but i have to set the form action into the php file and i am using CGI I Don't know how it should work!
**When** the **user** sign up the output is

> Hello None

What should I do??

```py
#if the user login

if (Username==form.getvalue('Username') and Password==form.getvalue('Password')) :
    print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print("<html>")
    print("<head>")
    print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
    print("</head>")
    print("<body>")
    print("<h2>Hello %s </h2>" % (Username))
    print("</body>")
    print("</html>")

#if the user sign up
elif (Username1==form.getvalue('Username1') and Email1==form.getvalue('Email1') and Password1==form.getvalue('Password1')):
    print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print("<html>")
    print("<head>")
    print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
    print("</head>")
    print("<body>")
    print("<h2>You have signed up !</h2>")
    print("<h4>Hello %s </h4>" % (Username1))
    print("<h4>your email is:%s </h4>" % (Email1))
    print("<h4>Your Password is: %s </h4>" % (Password1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 conditions are true, then so are just 2 of them, so the `if` condition will succeed.

You need to swap the order of the `if` and `elif` so that the more specific condition will be tested first.

```
if (Username1==form.getvalue('Username1') and Email1==form.getvalue('Email1') and Password1==form.getvalue('Password1')):
    print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print("<html>")
    print("<head>")
    print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
    print("</head>")
    print("<body>")
    print("<h2>You have signed up !</h2>")
    print("<h4>Hello %s </h4>" % (Username1))
    print("<h4>your email is:%s </h4>" % (Email1))
    print("<h4>Your Password is: %s </h4>" % (Password1))
elif (Username==form.getvalue('Username') and Password==form.getvalue('Password')) :
    print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print("<html>")
    print("<head>")
    print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
    print("</head>")
    print("<body>")
    print("<h2>Hello %s </h2>" % (Username))
    print("</body>")
    print("</html>")
```

Comment: i tried but this time the output is you have signed up! hello non your email is:non your password is :non

Comment: That means the variables match what they entered in the form. Why is that wrong? Please post more code that shows how you're setting the variables.

Comment: form= cgi.FieldStorage()
Username = form.getvalue('Username')
Password = form.getvalue('Password')

Username1 = form.getvalue('Username1')
Email1=form.getvalue('Email1')
Password1 = form.getvalue('Password1')

Comment: You're setting the variables from the form, and then comparing them to the form. Of course they're all equal. You should be looking for the form input in your user database.

Comment: would you specify how can i do it please ?

Comment: i did not create a database

Comment: i made a basic form with HTML and set the action to \cgi-bin\hello.py and the method is post

Comment: If you don't have a database, where are you storing the usernames and passwords? Wherever it is, you have to compare the passwords from the form with this, either to authenticate the user or check if the username is already in use.